# Generating 2-itemset rules with Arules in R

Tags: python, r, apriori, arules

I'm using Arules library in R to generate rules:

`rules = apriori(data = dataset, parameter = list(support = 0.001, confidence = 0.6, minlen=2))`

I understand the `minlen=2` avoids rules of the form `{} => {beer}`.

- In arules, is it possible to restrict rules such that LHS and RHS only has a
  single item? (i.e. Avoiding rules `{milk, nappies} => {beer}`)
- Alternatively, is the rule `{milk, nappies} => {beer}` equivalent to
  saying `{milk} => {beer}` and `{nappies} => {beer}`?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter the rules for rules having exactly one item on the LHS.

```
rules <- rules[sapply(
  1:length(rules)
  ,function(x) length(as(rules@lhs, "list")[[x]])) == 1];
```

I think, assuming [conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) of `{beer}` and `{milk}`, the rule `{milk, nappies} => {beer}` is equivalent to saying `{nappies} => {beer}`, and assuming conditional independence of `{beer}` and `{nappies}`, the rule `{milk, nappies} => {beer}` is equivalent to the rule `{milk} => {beer}`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but some future viewer may use this answer:

You can set maxlen parameter as 2.

```
    rules = apriori(data = dataset, parameter = list(support = 0.001, 
    confidence = 0.6, minlen=2, maxlen=2))
```